# How to save array of object as hash in redis?

Tags: redis, node-redis

I am using `redis` to save user information in a nodejs project. The user has below structure:

```
const user = {
    name: 'u1',
    age: 20,
    fav: [{x:0, y:0}, {x:1, y:1}]
}
```

when I save this data into redis through `node-redis` it gives me this warning message:

```
client.hmset(userId, user, err => {
    ...
}

node_redis: Deprecated: The HMSET command contains a argument of type Array.
This is converted to "[object Object],[object Object]" by using .toString() now and will return an error from v.3.0 on.
Please handle this in your code to make sure everything works as you intended it to.
```

and the data saved on redis is:

```
127.0.0.1:6379[2]> HGETALL 0
1) "name"
2) "u1"
3) "age"
4) "20"
5) "fav"
6) "[object Object],[object Object]"
```

I wonder what the best way to save an array of object in redis?

Comment: You could store the fav objects in a seperate set (or list, depends on whether they are unique). Use a key like u1:favs for it. You can load the user without the favs if you don't need them and get the favs with a second command

Comment: Do you mean I need to select a different database to store the fav object?

Comment: No not a different database. But you could store your users in a string like this (user:1 is the key, datatype is a string): user:1 -> {"name": u1, "age": 20,...}. And store the favs like this (with user:1:fav as key, datatype is a set or list): user:1:fav -> {x:0, y:0}, {x:1, y:1},...

Comment: Does this mean every time I need all data for the users requires two queries on the database? Another way to do that is to convert `hav` to a string by `JSON.stringrify` and parse it on the query. Which one is better for this case?

Answer (score 0):

After facing the same problem, I believe the most straightforward solution to save your data is:

```
client.hmset(userId, JSON.stringify(user), err => {...})
```

And when you retrieve your data, you just need after asking for userId data:

```
JSON.parse(user)
```